# DMOJ COCI'17 Contest 1 #1 Cezar

Tags: python, list, logic

I think there might be some flaw in the logic of my code, can someone please check it for me i cant figure it out.
The code produces the correct output with the sample input, but it fails when i submit the code to the judge.
Here's the [problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/coci17c1p1) and my code:

```
suits = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 16, 4]
ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
x = 21
drawn = int(input())
for i in range(drawn):
    card = int(input())
    left = ranks.index(card)
    suits[left] = suits[left] - 1
    x = x - card
total_g = 0
total_l = 0
for i in range(ranks.index(x)):
    total_l = total_l + suits[i]

for i in range(ranks.index(x) + 1, len(ranks)):
    total_g = total_g + suits[i]

if total_g >= total_l:
    print('DOSTA')
else:
    print('VUCI')
```

thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? All the sample input from the problem gave the correct output...

Comment: yeah but when i submit my code to the judge it gives a lot of errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.